# Comparing number values from a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to compare number values from a list, my list:

```
numberid = ["101", "102", "502", "503", "709", "809", "822", "922", "932", "940"]
```

I have been using `BeautifulSoup` to get number values from an `XML` file.

I want my code to print `("Matched number from numberid")` if the number from the `XML` file matches to a number in the list.

If the number from the `XML` file doesn't match the number in the `numberid` list then I want it to `print ("number does not match from numberid")`.

I'm pretty sure a simple if and else statement would complete this process but I'm having a struggle trying to work out how to write the code for the statement.

eg:

```
if 'number' == 101:
    print("match")
```

But instead of it for just one value, I'm trying to find out how to do it for the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to test if a specific value is present in a list.

```
numberid = ["101", "102", "502", "503", "709", "809", "822", "922", "932", "940"]
x = "102"

if x in numberid:
    print("Match found!")
else:
    print("No match found.")
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to do it instead of declaring 'x = "102". I'm trying to see if a number from my file is matched to a number in the numberid.

Comment: Okay, so instead of `x`, use whatever number value you got from the file.  You didn't provide any details about that file, so I can't answer any further.

Comment: My file has a list of number values inside of it and in my code I am trying to compare if the numbers in the file are a match to the values in my list. But not just for one value but multiple values in a file, so I will have to use an if and else statement right?

Comment: What is your actual problem here?  Are you able to fetch the numbers from the xml file?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to fetch all the numbers from the xml file, but I'm trying to compare the numbers with the numbers in the list in python to see if a specific number matches, it if matches I want it to be printed("Match"), if not ("No Match").

Comment: If you're able to fetch the numbers in the xml file, then I have to ask again, _what is your actual question_?  I provided a code sample that will check for a specific number in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know if a given number exists inside the list you can do:

```
if number in numberid:
    print('match')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of fetched numbers from a file you can use:

```
fetched_numbers = [...]
numberid = {"101", "102", "502", "503", "709", "809", "822", "922", "932", "940"}

for fn in fetched_numbers:
    if x in numberid:
        print("Match found!")
    else:
        print("No match found.")
```

use a set for your variable `numberid` because the search in a set is faster (O(1) time complexity)